# Add class inline if ... (in 1 line)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, if-statement, link-to

I want to add a class to a **link_to** only if a statement is true.

```
<%= link_to product.name, product, :class => "last" if product == @products.last %>
```

The problem that the IF statement affects the whole line and not just the **:class** part.

I know i can get it done with IF ELSE, but is it possible to do it in 1 line ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<%= link_to product.name, product, :class => (product == @products.last ? "last" : "")  %>
```

Comment: Cool, didn't thought of that.

Comment: is it "kosher" to have classes that are empty strings? rather than removing them?

If you add another class with javascript, will it have a class of "" and "anotherclass", or will it simply override the blank class string?

Answer (score 3):

Well you could abstract this away in a helper:

```
def product_link(product)
  if product == @products.last
    link_to product.name, product, :class => "last"
  else
    link_to product.name, product
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can just do `product_link(product)`.

**Update**: or in a more compact way:

```
def product_link(product)
  return link_to product.name, product, class: "last" if product == @products.last
  return link_to product.name, product)
end
```

Comment: The more compact way is indeed more compact, but it's many times more difficult to read.